# Azure how to enable full WebJob logs

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

When I run a console application as a WebJob in Windows Azure, after few lines of log it adds a warning:

```
[05/06/2014 09:42:40 > 21026c: WARN] Reached maximum allowed output lines for this run, to see all of the job's logs you can enable website application diagnostics
```

And stops logging. I was going through all settings in my Website with **BASIC** hosting plan but I was unable to find anything that would fix this issue.

How can I enable full webJob logs?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The way to enable full (continuous) WebJobs logs is actually in the error message: `enable website application diagnostics`, you can do this via the Azure portal on the website's CONFIGURE tab, you can set the application logs to go to either the file-system (but only for 12 hours), table storage or blob storage.

Once enabled the full logs for WebJobs will go on the selected storage.

More info on application diagnostics for Azure websites: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log/

Comment: Is it possible to use NLog file target with WebJobs? I have a continuous job that runs during the night and can sometimes have errors I won't see until the next day and I would like continuous logging with a rolling archive--all of which NLog can do. Is there a path in the file system the WJ has write access to?

Comment: yes, it will be whatever the website has access to which is anything under d:\home (%home%), go to https://{sitename}.scm.azurewebsites.net/debugconsole to see your files and there you can understand where best to put your files / log files

Comment: I have a continuous WebJob running and application diagnostics is ON for table storage, still I get `Reached maximum allowed output lines for this run, to see all of the job's logs you can enable website application diagnostics` after some time. The WebJob run a simple C# console app with an infinite while-loop, not using the WebJob SDK. I do a few lines of output every minute using `Console.WriteLine`. Do you have an idea of why I still receive this message?

Comment: You only see this line in the log file (on the file system) logs to the table storage will not show this and will continue receiving log lines.

Comment: @AmitApple I see, then is there some way to tell the site at `https://[mysite].scm.azurewebsites.net/azurejobs/#/jobs/continuous/[myjob]` to show the output of the table storage log, instead of the file system log?

Comment: No, as currently there is no tagging of these logs so it is impossible to extract the right log lines fir the specific job. You are welcome to open an issue on this in https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues

Comment: @AmitApple Just opened [a new issue](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/1421), as per your request.

Comment: @AmitApple I don't see an option to select destination for logs in my Web App's "Diagnostic logs" blade. Is there a condition where this is not an available choice?

Comment: @Michael the new azure portal still doesn't support this, pleae use the current azure portal for configuring application logs for your web app.

Comment: This has now moved.  Its now in the new portal under the app service and "Diagnostic logs"

Answer (score 4):

You could also potentially use a custom TraceWriter.

Example: https://gist.github.com/aaronhoffman/3e319cf519eb8bf76c8f3e4fa6f1b4ae

`JobHost` config

```
static void Main()
{
    var config = new JobHostConfiguration();

    // Log Console.Out to SQL using custom TraceWriter
    // Note: Need to update default Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs package for config.Tracing.Tracers to be exposed/available
    config.Tracing.Tracers.Add(new SqlTraceWriter(
        TraceLevel.Info,
        "{{SqlConnectionString}}",
        "{{LogTableName}}"));

    var host = new JobHost(config);
    host.RunAndBlock();
}
```

Sample SqlTraceWriter implementation

```
public class SqlTraceWriter : TraceWriter
{
    private string SqlConnectionString { get; set; }

    private string LogTableName { get; set; }

    public SqlTraceWriter(TraceLevel level, string sqlConnectionString, string logTableName)
        : base(level)
    {
        this.SqlConnectionString = sqlConnectionString;
        this.LogTableName = logTableName;
    }

    public override void Trace(TraceEvent traceEvent)
    {
        using (var sqlConnection = this.CreateConnection())
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();

            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(string.Format("insert into {0} ([Source], [Timestamp], [Level], [Message], [Exception], [Properties]) values (@Source, @Timestamp, @Level, @Message, @Exception, @Properties)", this.LogTableName), sqlConnection))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Source", traceEvent.Source ?? "");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Timestamp", traceEvent.Timestamp);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Level", traceEvent.Level.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Message", traceEvent.Message ?? "");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Exception", traceEvent.Exception?.ToString() ?? "");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Properties", string.Join("; ", traceEvent.Properties.Select(x => x.Key + ", " + x.Value?.ToString()).ToList()) ?? "");

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }

    private SqlConnection CreateConnection()
    {
        return new SqlConnection(this.SqlConnectionString);
    }
}
```