# Azure - can't solve Reached maximum allowed output lines

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk, azure-log-analytics, azure-webjobs-continuous

I have a web continuous job and see in log:

> Reached maximum allowed output lines for this run, to see all of the
>   job's logs you can enable website application diagnostics

I have googled, found how to solve it, for example:
[Azure how to enable full WebJob logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23491907/azure-how-to-enable-full-webjob-logs)

I did all these actions and have the following settings:

[image]

But message still occurs. What is wrong yet?

PS. Restart app helps for adding approx +100 messages, then I see the same error again

Comment: Check to the suggestions mentioned in the below link:https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/1748 and https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/blob/44570100217a560563ce577cebc8be8fba470a96/Kudu.Core/Jobs/FilePerJobLogger.cs#L76

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enabling logs will not stop this message from appearing. What it does is send your logs to the configured blob storage, which you can then analyze there. So this behavior is expected.

Comment: It would seem like there should be a setting to "roll" the log screen.
Meaning, drop off the old stuff and at least show the new.
going to blob storage is a bit cumbersome when all you want to do is check something quick.